# Generating 3 random numbers that sum to 1 with two different methods.

Tags: probability, statistics

I am looking at ways to generate three random numbers that sum to $1$. I came up with two different methods and played around with some code and they seem to have *very* different distributions.

**Method 1**

Generate $3$ Uniform$[0,1]$ variables and then divide by their sum :

[image: Method 1]

**Method 2**

For this method I imagined picking 2 points on a stick of length 1, ensuring that their sum would always be 1, and then using the two points to break the stick into 3 pieces.

[image]

**Quick look at the methods**

It is clear to see in Method 1 the distribution of all three outputs will be the same, that is all three outputs are completely symmetrical. This is also true for Method 2 but takes some more thinking to see why. It should be clear by another reflection/symmetry argument that min and 1 - max have the same distribution and by a bijective reflection around max/2 it is clear to see that max - min has the same distribution as min.

**Breakdown and Problem**

I then ran a few thousand simulations of each method and we get vastly different results.

**Results method 1**

[image]

**Results method 2**
[image]

**The question**

Method 1 seems somewhat poisson like whereas method 2 feels to be more uniform. What is the correct way to generate n numbers that sum to 1? Why are these results so different? Have we constricted the ability to be random by demanding they sum to 1?

Comment: You have stumbled upon a version of an old probability teaser: if you break a stick into three pieces, what is the probability that you can make a triangle with those three pieces as the sides? There are different procedures for breaking the stick, each of which is a reasonable interpretation of the problem, and they lead to different probabilities for forming a triangle. There's really no way around it, unless you have some actual application in mind, in which case you may be able to decide which of the many procedures best fits your application.

Comment: By the way, I see two older questions, listed under "Related", that would seem to be relevant here. Here's one discussion of the stick-breaking question (although it doesn't mention alternatives, just picks one procedure): https://services.math.duke.edu/education/webfeatsII/gdrive/Team%20D/project/brokenstick.htm See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2014/if-you-break-a-stick-at-two-points-chosen-uniformly-the-probability-the-three-r

Comment: And here's a good discussion of stick-breaking: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Probability/TriProbability.shtml also https://www.themathdoctors.org/broken-sticks-triangles-and-probability-ii/ There are also several Youtube videos about the question!

Comment: "*What is the correct way*"  That is up to the question-asker.  Unless specified there is no "correct" way and the problem cannot be answered unless clarified.  See also [Bertrand's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)).

Comment: Any thoughts on the comments, Bear?

Comment: Hello everyone I only just received these comments now! I never knew such an easy sounding questions could be so complicated! I was expecting a simple enough answer like "method 1 wrong only use method 2" It seems to be the case that by restricting a sum on the numbers we loose the ability to have a "pure " (organic) way to generate the integers. I found lots of cool other ways to do it too! Thanks for the literature @GerryMyerson

Comment: @JMoravitz thats for sending the paradox, exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 2):

Someone just pointed out to me that the Dirichlet distribution is also a good way to generate such triplets, and with $\alpha = (1, 1, 1)$, it happens to give the same results as method 2, providing some support/justification for that method. For what it’s worth, the marginal probability distributions from method 2 also have higher entropy than those from method 1.

It also means that method 2 can be implemented as:

```
return scipy.stats.dirichlet((1, 1, 1)).rvs()
```

Or like method 1 but with `np.random.exponential()` instead of `np.random.rand()`.